# Removing/deleting a table from a datacontext

Tags: .net, datacontext

I want to display a list of the tables/classes in a datacontext, select several and delete them from the datacontext.  I know how to get the list of tables, but how do I programmatically delete/remove them from the datacontext?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how do you select several items to delete, however if you are using LINQ and select them via a query you can use the following code:

```
var items = DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId);
foreach(var item in items)
 DataContext.Items.DeleteObject(item);
```

Comment: Is this for the LINQ to SQL datacontext or some other datacontext?  I don't see the Items property on my LINQ to SQL datacontext.

Comment: This one is using LINQ on database table. IF you are using LINQ to SQL DataContext, you can try this: http://www.ezineasp.net/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Delete-Operation-using-C-sharp.aspx

Comment: I don't want to delete records from a table.  Imagine you are looking at the "tables" (actually mapped classes) in the OR designer of the datacontext/dbml.  In the designer, I could select a table(class), hit the Delete button, and remove it from the design surface.  I want to be able to do the same thing, but programmatically.